# Как сделать проверку на наличие записи в базе данных

Tags: python, sqlite

Имею базу данных sqlite, в ней есть такие столбики: id, name
Как сделать чтобы один и тот же пользователь не смог записаться в базу данных второй раз?

Comment: сделать поле name unique

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто сделать UNIQUE или же проверку, к примеру что бы ты понял суть

```
def check(LOGIN):# Проверим существует ли пользователь
    ***
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `login`= %s"
    cursor.execute(SQL, (LOGIN))
    return cursor.fetchall()
    ***

def add_user(LOGIN, PASSWORD):# Добавим пользователя
    ***
    sql = "INSERT INTO user `login`, `password` VALUES (%s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (LOGIN, PASSWORD)
    ***

if check('bla@bla.ru') == None: # Если пользователя нет, то
    add_user('bla@bla.ru', 'qwer1234')
```